# Android Bubble tab Indicator. Customize Android Tab selected item

Tags: android, material-design, android-tabs

I came across a library but for flutter. How to customize selected item in tabs, like the Crane app from google or more specifically how to implement bubble tab Indicator? Or the one in the picture below please?

[image: shazam tab selected]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using these repositories, hopefully they are useful to you:

1. [SmartTabLayout](https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout)
2. [un-material tab](https://github.com/creageek/un-material-tab) (deprecated)

Comment: Thanks. I want to implement it myself without using any 3rd party library, as Google show it in their Crane app(in Material design case study), I was wondering if ther's not a simpler way to do this